# Fancybox 1.3.4 - no overlay after reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I'm developing a `ajax` popup system. One of functionalities is, when ajax gathers any new data, to show it using Fancybox. There are two scenarios:

1. user reads data brought by `ajax`, and closes fancybox.
2. user is AFK. When another data comes in, it should be **appended** to already displaying fancybox content

my html container for fancybox looks like this:

```
<div id="notifications_fancybox">
  <div class="notifications_fancybox_title">
    Powiadomienia
  </div>
  <div id="notifications_fancybox_content">

  </div>
</div>
```

where `notifications_fancybox` has `display: none;` in css.

Fist I wanted to just `$('#otifications_fancybox_content').append('some html');` append some data, but it seems that after fancybox have been initialized, somehow it won't let me append anything.

So I found another way to do that:

When new data comes in, first check if fancybox is already opened:

```
nl.isFancyboxOpened = function(){
    if($('#fancybox-wrap').is(':visible')) return true;
    return false;
};
```

if it is opened, close it:

```
if(nl.isFancyboxOpened()){
    $.fancybox.close();
}
```

append some data

```
$('#otifications_fancybox_content').append('some html');
```

and open fancybox

```
nl.openFancybox = function(){   
    if(nl.isFancyboxOpened() == false){
      $.fancybox(
        $('#notifications_fancybox').html(),
        {
          'autoDimensions'            : false,
          'overlayShow'               : true,
          'hideOnOverlayClick'        : false,
          'showCloseButton'           : true,
          'width'                     : 450,
          'height'                    : 400,
          'transitionIn'              : 'none',
          'transitionOut'             : 'none'
        }
      );

    }
    else{
      $.fancybox.resize();
    }
};
```

**Now, the main problem**:
When fancybox is displayed for the first time, everything is fine - there's overlay, buttons and so on.

When more ajax data comes for being displayed and I try to go through above procedure (close-append-reopen), everything again seems fine except... there is no overlay! So user can click on everything on the page, and I don't want him to.

Comment: can you share a link?

Comment: unfortunely I can't - corpo intranet system. Good news is that I've managed to solve the problem... not exactly what I wanted, but works good enough. Details in next reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to solve the problem. Not exactly what I wanted, but I'll work fine enough.

My solution uses `onComplete` callback to force `display` property of overlay to be set to `block`. It's packed in `setTimeout` because calling it instantly won't work. Also reducing timeout below certain time will cause this solution to fail. I believe there's a better way to solve this, but I haven't found one... yet ;)

```
$.fancybox(
        $('#notifications_fancybox').html(),
        {
          'autoDimensions'            : false,
          'overlayShow'               : true,
          'hideOnOverlayClick'        : false,
          'showCloseButton'           : true,
          'onComplete'                : function(){setTimeout(function(){$('#fancybox-overlay').css('display', 'block');}, 250);},
          'width'                     : 450,
          'height'                    : 400,
          'transitionIn'              : 'none',
          'transitionOut'             : 'none'
        }
);
```